# Sublime Text 2 Theme package gets automatically removed

Tags: git, sublimetext2

I am using Sublime Text 2 and 3 on Fedora 17 64-bit machine.

**Issue**

1. I install Theme package into sublime Package folder using git, and it works fine. This is the command that I use to install.

   git clone git://github.com/jaromero/soda-refined-theme.git "Theme - Soda Refined"
2. Few hours later, I close the editor and re-open the editor. Editor breaks down saying theme could not be found. Editor has weird red-ish colors all over the place. I check the Package folder, and the theme foler is removed.
3. I re-install the Theme using above command again, and the theme works fine now. And this install-auto_removal-reinstall cycle loops forever.

I am not sure what triggers the theme to be auto-removed, and therefore don't exactly know what information I need to provide in this post. Please comment on necessary information to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control)? It may "stick" better using that method, and it automatically keeps it up to date. The other option is to try installing it to your `Packages/User` directory, as that is specifically for user stuff.